# How to turnoff 'hits' in elasticsearch response

Tags: elasticsearch

Following is the sample response for

`curl -X POST "http://localhost:9200/articles/_search?pretty=true" -d '
{
  "facets": {
    "speaker" : { "terms" : {"field" : "speaker"} }
  }
}'`

Sample response

```
{
"took": 16,
"timed_out": false,
"_shards": {
    "total": 5,
    "successful": 5,
    "failed": 0
},
"hits": {
    "total": 111396,
    "max_score": 1,
    "hits": [
        {
            "_index": "shakespeare",
            "_type": "line",
            "_id": "63098",
            "_score": 1,
            "_source": {
                "line_id": 63099,
                "play_name": "Merchant of Venice",
                "speech_number": 5,
                "line_number": "3.3.14",
                "speaker": "SHYLOCK",
                "text_entry": "Ill have my bond; and therefore speak no more."
            }
        },
        {
            "_index": "shakespeare",
            "_type": "line",
            "_id": "63101",
            "_score": 1,
            "_source": {
                "line_id": 63102,
                "play_name": "Merchant of Venice",
                "speech_number": 5,
                "line_number": "3.3.17",
                "speaker": "SHYLOCK",
                "text_entry": "To Christian intercessors. Follow not;"
            }
        }

    ]
},
"facets": {
    "speaker": {
        "_type": "terms",
        "missing": 0,
        "total": 111396,
        "other": 100157,
        "terms": [
            {
                "term": "GLOUCESTER",
                "count": 1920
            },
            {
                "term": "HAMLET",
                "count": 1582
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

}

Can somebody explain this hits part of the response.

- Why `hits.hits` is an array?
- What does each of the hits object mean ?
- Is there a way to suppress hits from the elastic search response ?

Comment: Why the downvote? Note: facets were replaced by aggregations: `facets have been replaced by aggregations in Elasticsearch 1.0, which are a superset of facets.` I have wanted aggregation results without hit results, I think that's the spirit of Venkat's question. Even if Elasticsearch does the same work either way, an empty hits array makes the response smaller.

Comment: @TheRedPea You got me right.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

- `hits.hits` is array of found documents that meet your search query
- Each object represent single found document - you can see here its id, type and attributes inside `_source` object
- You can specify `"size" : 0` clause in your search query and then `hits.hits` array will be empty